# Cucumber Jvm Before All scenario

Tags: selenium, jvm, cucumber

In Cucumber jvm, if we have multiple scenario and is there any option to execute all the scenario in one instance. I mean opening the browser once and executing all the scenarios instead of opening and closing browser for each scenario.

I tried with BeforeAll in the hooks file but its throwing Nullpointer Exception.

Here my code. I need to goto the URL, login with credentials and execute both the scenario at the same instance.

MaharaTest.feature

```
Feature: MaharaTest
  Scenario: Creating Profile
    Given I navigate to Content Tab
    And I enter firstname
    And I enter lastname
    And I click save profile
    Then I see profile saved successful message
  Scenario: Creating Profile
    Given I navigate to Portfolio Tab
    And I click create page
    And I enter page title
    And I click save page
    Then I see page saved successful message
```

MaharaTest.java

```
public class MaharaTest {
    public WebDriver driver;
    public MaharaTest() {
        driver = Hooks.driver;
    }

    @Given("^I navigate to Content Tab$")
    public void navigate_to_content() {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Content")).click();
    }

    @And("^I enter firstname$")
    public void enter_firstname() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("profileform_firstname")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("profileform_firstname")).sendKeys("Test");
    }

    @And("^I enter lastname$")
    public void enter_lastname() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("profileform_lastname")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("profileform_lastname")).sendKeys("User");
    }

    @And("^I click save profile$")
    public void click_save() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("profileform_submit")).click();
    }

    @Then("^I see profile saved successful message$")
    public void profile_success_message() {
        assertEquals("Profile saved successfully",
                driver.findElement(By.className("alert-success")).getText());
    }

    @Given("^I navigate to Portfolio Tab$")
    public void navigate_to_portfolio() {
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Portfolio")).click();
    }

    @And("^I click create page$")
    public void create_page() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("createview_submit")).click();
    }

    @And("^I enter page title$")
    public void enter_page_title() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("editview_title")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("editview_title")).sendKeys("Test_Profile");
    }

    @And("^I click save page$")
    public void click_save_page() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("editview_submit")).click();
    }

    @Then("^I see page saved successful message$")
    public void page_success_message() {
        assertEquals("Page saved successfully",
                driver.findElement(By.className("alert-success")).getText());
    }
}
```

Hooks.java

```
public class Hooks {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    @Before
    public void openBrowser() throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("Called openBrowser");
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://demo.mahara.org/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_login_username")).sendKeys("student1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_login_password")).sendKeys("Testing1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("login_submit")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void embedScreenshot(Scenario scenario) {

        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
            try {
                scenario.write("Current Page URL is " + driver.getCurrentUrl());
                byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver)
                        .getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
            } catch (WebDriverException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
                System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots
                        .getMessage());
            }

        }
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you seem to be wanting to do two things here

Create a profile
Create a portfolio page

I'm assuming that you can't create a portfolio page unless you have created a profile.

One way to do this is:

```
Scenario: Create a profile
  When I create a profile
  Then I should see my new profile
```

That should be enough to drive the development of creating profiles. Once you can create a profile then you can do

```
Scenario: Create portfolio page
  Given I have a profile
  When I create a portfolio page
  Then I should see my new portfolio page
```

There are two ways you can implement `Given I have a profile`

1. Execute exactly the same code you used `When you created a profile`, i.e. go through the UI.
2. Find a faster way to create the same effect (generally bypassing the UI)

If you want a fast set of features, you'll take the second approach.

Some things to note:

There is no need to put any detail about 'how' you create a profile/page in your scenarios. Scenarios should be about what and why not how, so no clicking on buttons or filling in fields (leave that to the step defs)

Because we write a very fast (Given I have a profile) we can use it in lots and lost of scenarios, without worrying about how long it takes.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But again if i need to execute a 2nd scenario i.e Create portfolio page, it will launch a new window only right instead of working on the same browser launched for 1st scenario, how to overcome this?